# http.get request stuck in pending

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

This is working on different PC. However when I change a PC for some reason when I try to fetch data from the server, the http request is stuck in pending. This is the URL I am trying to reach.

```
app.get('/api/allusers', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  Employee.find().then(retrievedData => { res.json(retrievedData) })
})
```

and the console log successfully logs in when I try to access it, but for some reason the request  is stuck in pending state according to the network tab and after some time it time out and throws unknown error.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ciCW.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

kind regards,

Comment: _"from server"_, you're requesting localhost, so you need the same server configuration on your _different PC_

Comment: Check that same URL you can access from browser or not. Also target api is localhost, so you need to make api in running mode in your new machine.

Comment: Enter full url of API end point

Comment: I am listening on port 3000

Comment: app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Up and running'));

Comment: getEmployees() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/allusers/');
  }

Comment: And I am trying to access that URL

Comment: Also I am trying to get the URL with postman it fails also.